# compass.cfg.xml path in grails project with searchable plugin

Tags: grails, searchable, compass-lucene

I installed searchable in my grails project. As I already had the java POJO classes I want to use compass for the mapping customisation.
However, it seams that the Searchable.groovy looks for a file compass.cfg.xml at the root of my classpath. This folder is my PROJECT_HOME folder. I also tried to put him at /src/java
or in grails-app folder but the the file is not found => compass cannot start!

Is there a way to customize the path of the compass.cfg.xml?

PS: I run my project with run-app!

Answer (score 0):

For the plug in to find it, it needs to be in the classpath so if you put it under grails-app/conf it should find it with no problem, I have used it like this before.